# IAM role used by cloudformation stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to know which IAM service role was used in the creation of a stack? I was able to create stacks before but it fails with permissions issues now, want to figure out what changed that prevents me from creating stacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, an Amazon CloudFormation stack runs with the permissions of the user that creates the stack.

Alternatively an IAM Role can be specified during stack creation. If the user has permission to use that IAM Role, then the stack will be created using the permissions of that Role.

See: [AWS CloudFormation Service Role - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html)

The [`describe_stacks()` API call](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.describe_stacks) can be used to obtain the `RoleARN` that is used by a stack.

Comment: Okay, if the stack was run without using users permission - instead an IAM role was selected - my question is how to find what role was selected when CF was created.

Comment: Updated answer: Use `describe_stacks()`